# Is Genesis 28:20-22 intended as a description of Jacob's conversion/"becoming a true Jew"?

Tags: genesis

Is Genesis 28:20-22 intended as a description of Jacob's conversion/"becoming a true Jew"? If not, what is being described?

> [Gen 28:20-22 NASB95] [20] Then Jacob made a vow, saying, "If God will be with me and will keep me on this journey that I take, and will give me food to eat and garments to wear, [21] and I return to my father's house in safety, then the LORD will be my God. [22] "This stone, which I have set up as a pillar, will be God's house, and of all that You give me I will surely give a tenth to You."

Comment: Reposted here:  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138315/is-genesis-2820-22-intended-as-a-description-of-jacobs-conversion-becoming-a

It is interesting how different the answers are there!

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 28 gives the full account of Jacob being sent to the land of his mother's family to find a wife there; of his older twin-brother Esau despising parental wishes and choosing a wife from Ishmael's clan. But the significance of this with regard to the question lies in chapter 25. There the twins' mother, Rebekah, entreats the Lord, who answers her:

> "Two nations are in thy womb, and two manner of people shall be
> separated from thy bowels; and the one people shall be stronger than
> the other people; and the elder shall serve the younger." Genesis
> 25:23 K.J.

The account in question cannot be about Jacob becoming 'converted' or, 'a true Jew' any more than it can be about him being converted to faith in Christ, or becoming either a literal or a spiritual spiritual Jew. The Jewish nation no more existed on Earth at the time of Jacob than did Jesus Christ. The account is bound up with Jacob coming to personally know and trust the God of his forebears. **It was about Jacob realising the older promise, of how a nation would come from him, blessed of God. That is what is being described in the text in question**. He already knew about this God of Abraham and Isaac. The whole family did. That is why, when Jacob set out to obey his father's command to find a wife from his mother's brother's family, his father, Isaac, blessed him with these words:

> "And God Almighty bless thee, and make thee fruitful, and multiply
> thee, that thou mayest be a multitude of people; and give thee the
> blessing of Abraham, to thee and to thy seed with thee; that thou
> mayest inherit the land wherein thou art a stranger, which God gave
> unto Abraham." Genesis 28:2-5 A.V.

On his way, Jacob had a dream of a ladder set up on the earth, its top in heaven, with angels of God ascending and descending on it. The Lord stood above it, declaring himself to be the God of Abraham and Isaac, promising to give Jacob and his seed the land where he lay. He repeated the God-given promise to Abraham of his seed spreading over the land, and "in thee and thy seed shall all the families of the earth be blessed." God promised this to Jacob, adding that wherever he went, God would bring him back to that promised land. (Genesis 28:11-15)

Jacob awoke, afraid, as he knew the Lord was in that place. He took the stone that had been for his pillows, set it up, anointed it with oil, and called the place Beth-el. Then he vowed to God, as in the verses quoted in the question. All this background is vital if the question is to be answered properly.

The chapters following show what happened over many years when he was tricked into marrying the eldest daughter of Laban, having to then work more years for the younger daughter he loved, Rachel. They both bore him children. When his father-in-law's duplicity turned to anger, God instructed Jacob:

> "Return unto the land of thy fathers, and to thy kindred, and I will
> be with thee... I am the God of Beth-el, where thou anointedst the
> pillar, where thou vowed a vow unto me. Now arise, get thee out from
> this land, and return unto the land of thy kindred." Genesis 31:3 & 13
> A.V. See also *Shared Life*, Donald Macleod, pp.12-13 Christian Focus 1994 & *Hosea,* Michael Eaton, pp.171-176, Christian Focus 1996

The account goes on to show **how Jacob returned in faith to the land of his father, along with his wives and children, trusting God to give him that land and to make his descendants into its inheritors. That is what those verses describe.** By the time of Moses, his offspring had grown into a very large group known as the Haribu, who did not become the nation of Israel until God, through Moses, released them from bondage in Egypt. Then, at the foot of Mount Sinai, that bunch of despised people became the nation of Israel. That is what all those chapters combine to show as to the significance of Jacob's vow in Genesis 28:20-22.

Answer (score 0):

I have always understood Gen 28:20-22 as a simple expression of Jacob's acceptance of the divine covenant made with Abraham (Gen 12:1-3, Gen 15, Gen 17, Gen 18:9-15) which was inherited and then reconfirmed to both Isaac and Jacob.  We are told this numerous times in places like:

- Ex 2:24 - So God heard their groaning, and He remembered His **covenant** with Abraham, Isaac, and **Jacob**.
- Deut 9:5 - It is not because of your righteousness or uprightness of heart that you are going in to possess their land, but it is because of their wickedness that the LORD your God is driving out these nations before you, to **keep the promise** He swore to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and **Jacob**.
- Deut 29:13 - and so that He may establish you today as His people, and He may **be your God as He promised** you and as He swore to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and **Jacob**.
- 2 Kings 13:23 - But the LORD was gracious to Israel and had compassion on them, and He turned toward them because of His **covenant** with Abraham, Isaac, and **Jacob**. And to this day, the LORD has been unwilling to destroy them or cast them from His presence.
- 1 Chron 16:17 - He confirmed it to **Jacob** as a decree, to **Israel** as an everlasting **covenant**:
- etc

Thus, Jacob, at this point (Gen 28) decided to abide by (ie, accept) the covenant requirements and accept the covenant advantages and promises.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be picky, but at this point there aren't any Jews -- that name doesn't apply until the time of the Exile from Judah.  That said--

Jacob states an "if . . . then" pair of propositions.  The first is what he wants from God, and the second is a declaration of how he will respond.  In essence he is proposing continuing God's covenant with his father Isaac and his grandfather Jacob, not as their offspring but as his own person.  He invokes a common form of covenant, an expectation of what a sovereign will do for him followed by a declaration of loyalty.

This is in response to God telling Jacob that the promise He had made to Abraham and renewed with Isaac now included Jacob as well.  The situation was that Jacob was being sent off to Paddan-aram to relatives to find a wife, which was a long journey especially on foot.  A normal human reaction to such a journey when not having undertaken one before is to be nervous, which probably wasn't helped by God appearing in a dream.  So he dealt with being nervous by making his proposed covenant with its declaration of loyalty.

So this isn't really a conversion; he already knew of God and the covenant with his father and grandfather.  It's more a personal commitment, something similar to confirmation in many churches today: a step of no longer relying on one's parents for one's relationship to God and instead taking personal responsibility.